# Python pulp solvers

Tags: python, solver, pulp

I am new with python pulp and I have been trying to install another solver than the default one I have currently (GLPK_CMD), do you know any why of installing / downloading another solver like PULP_CBC for example?

Thank you in advance!

I looked in a lot of resources but didn't find any useful information on how to be able to have other solvers

Comment: Did you try this guide? https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_configure_solvers.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you successfully installed `pulp`, you already have `cbc`...  it is included in the `pulp` installation.  Just try solving a model and not specifying the solver, `cbc` should be the default